# Dart tag and syntax reference?

Tags: syntax, reference, tags, dart

This is a very noobie question. I hope I still can get some help. I normally use references for the languages I use. Like Tag and Syntax references so I know what they do. A example would be If I was doing HTML I would have this site open http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp

I do this because I can't remember anything. It seems like w3school does not have dart yet so I was wondering if any other Dart coders found something similar?

If there is none what do you guys do to know all the syntaxes/tags? Do you remember everything?

Dartlang.org only has the API reference and some code samples which is good but not enough for me
https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/home

Answer (score 1):

[Dart cheat sheet](http://dartlangfr.net/dart-cheat-sheet/) is a concise and clearly arranged summary of the Dart language.

Comment: It doesn't give the definition or say what it does like the HTML example. Thanks for the link tho it will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Chapter 2. A Tour of the Dart Language](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html) from the web version of [Dart Up and Running](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/).

It's concise but quite useful, and published as a single we page so it can be searched with the browser search function.